# TaffyDB: Select problems

Tags: javascript, json, taffydb

I'm new to TaffyDB and haven't done a lot of javascript programming so I'm hoping that the problem I'm having is something simple. I'm trying to update a listbox with the options stored in the TaffyDB according to the selected client. When I do my select however, it is returning all the rows.

Below is the code I am using to update the listbox, along with the selectString used to do the query, and what's in the TaffyDB.

Anyone have any ideas why I am getting back all rows when I specify clientID = 1788?

I tried the select string with and without quotes around the column identifier.

```
// load existing user client projects if we have any
var lbProjects = document.getElementById('lbProjects');
lbProjects.options.length = 0;
var selectString = '{clientID:"' + clientID + '"}';
alert(selectString);
userProjects(selectString).each(
function (r) {
    var option = new Option();
    option.value = r.projectID;
    option.text = r.projectName;
    lbProjects.add(option, null);
});
```

What's in selectString:
    {clientID:"1788"}

What's in the DB:
    [{"clientID":"1788","projectID":"19"},
    {"clientID":"1789","projectID":"24"}, 
    {"clientID":"1790","projectID":"23"}]

Thanks for any help.
Aaron L. Bratcher

Answer (score 1):

The problem was trying to use the selectString variable.

The line

```
userProjects(selectString).each(
```

now reads

```
userProjects({clientID: clientIDValue}).each(
```

I was supposed to be passing in an object array, not a string. {} in javascript creates an array of objects.

Comment: so you have solved your own problem? why don't you choose this answer?